# Different ways in which a micro-switch with eight switches can set

Tags: permutations

A computer interface for a Kawai digital studio piano has eight micro-switches that can be set in either the "on" or "off" position. These switches must be set properly for the interface to work. In how many different ways can this group of switches be set?

Am not sure if this is a permutation problem. I have tried to reason out using two switches whereby, one can be on the other on, one on the other off, one off the other on and one off the other off. I have discovered that this can happen four times. However when I use permutation am getting 2! which is 2 and thus they aren't giving the same result. Am afraid if I use 8! case with 8 switches I might not get it right.

Comment: Try $2^8 = 256$

Comment: I think that works out. Appreciative